# How to change element.style to none with css on all pages

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, styles

guys I have a website on WordPress where I want to hide reviews tab on all product pages, currently I am using CSS hero to make changes but it applies only on the single page. I couldn't find a way to hide it on all pages, I can just do it by the changing element.style from block to none in inspect element, But I don't know how to apply it on my website. Here is the screenshot of the problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to one of the public CSS that exist in all Pages.

```
.tab-content.tab-reviews {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will hide the class `tab-content` completely.

```
.tab-content{display:none !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same class name on other product pages too? If so, one way is to add a style:

```
.tab-reviews {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

classes may be repeated but `ID`'s must be unique , please add your style with `id` like below

```
#content_tab_reviews {
   display:none !important;
}
```